# Props not being passed from Parent to Child element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swr, react-usememo

I have a question regarding data passing between parent/child element.
The parent element StylePage retrieves data via [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) which retrieves the data without problem and the application is able to display it with a Text. Problem is that it isn't being passed to the child element (StyleCard). The same goes with `currentAssets`. **What have I missed here that might cause the props not being passed to StyleCard?**

```
// StylePage
export default function StylePage(): JSX.Element {
  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/styles/style-number/${styleNumber}`);

  const currentAssets = useMemo(() => {
    const result: IAsset[] = data?.assets?.map(x => {
      return {
            perspective_number: x.perspective.number,
            storage_url: x.file.storageUrl
          } as IAsset
    })
    return result;
  }, [data?.assets]);

  return (
    <Stack spacing={6}>
       <Stack ml="100px" minWidth="480px" maxWidth="480px">

        <StyleCard
           assets={currentAssets}               // Has value but doesn't display
           styleNumber={data?.styleNumber} />   // Has value but doesn't display 
        <Text>{data?.name}</Text>               // Displays value 

       </Stack>
     </Stack>
  );
}
```

```
// StyleCard
export interface IStyleCard{
   assets: IAsset[],
   styleNumber: number
}

export function StyleCard(
  props: IStyleCard
): JSX.Element {

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Text> Props Assets {JSON.stringify(props.assets)}</Text> // Props.assets is empty
      <Text> Props styleNumber {props.styleNumber}</Text>       // props.styleNumber is blank
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Edit:
There's a global configuration `SWRConfig` [(source)](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/global-configuration) which is wrapped around the top layer component. That's why fetcher isn't specified in StylePage.
Also fixing a typo in the code sample.

```
    <SWRConfig
      value={{
        refreshInterval: 3000,
        fetcher: (url) =>
          axios
            .get(url)
            .then((res) => res.data),
      }}
    >

    ... 

    </SWRConfig>
```

Comment: There's a typo in type definition of `StyleCard`. It should be `assets` instead of `asset`

Comment: I see in the swr documentation that they are using a fetcher as a second parameter `useSWR('/api/data', fetcher)`.  I don't see it in your code, is that normal ? Are you sure the data are corretly retrieved currently ?

Comment: @NeERAJTK Thanks, that was a typo in the code sample. The behaviour remains the same.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Thanks for your reply. I edited the question and added an explanation on why the fetcher isn't specified.

Comment: Are you certain you're getting the expected response from the `axios` request?